# Writing a jQuery AJAX request using a plain JS promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I am currently moving my webpage over to a SPA (single page application) and in doing so I am now working with only one html page, which gets populated using JS (as a normal SPA should do). As such, that means (for convenience sake) I am cutting down my JS files to one (maybe a good idea, maybe a bad one - we'll see, but that's not the point). I have decided to make a "black box" AJAX request handler, so as to minimize code. This is where I ran into a problem I was not expecting. The code is (the example `click` is for my login screen):

```
function ajaxCall(type, url, data, dataType) {
  $.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: dataType,
  })
  .done(function(xhr) {
    return xhr;
  })
  .fail(function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
    console.log('AJAX call error: ' + errorThrown);
    console.dir(xhr);
  })
  .always(function(xhr, status) {
    console.log('AJAX call status: ' + status);
  });
}

var res;
//this is inside $(document).ready - I just skipped some lines
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function(e) {
  res = ajaxCall('POST', '/Login', { 'username': $('#username').val(), 'password': $('#password').val() }, 'json');

  console.log('res =', res); // this is where the problem was discovered
});
```

(some of you are already groaning) Of course, when I tested this, what I got in my console is `res = undefined`.

*I have spent hours researching this problem, and have figured out why it happens*. These are some of the pages I researched in trying to solve this: [1](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-javascript-promises) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

To cut to the chase: The problem is that I am not using a `Promise`. I got that. I can fix that. What I cannot seem to fix is using a plain JS `Promise` with a jQuery AJAX request.

I have gotten this far:

```
function ajaxCall(type, url, data, dataType) {
  return Promise.resolve($.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: dataType,
  }));
}
```

**but I cannot figure out how to incorporate the other features/functions of a `promise`, which are: `.then() and .reject()`.** As far as I understand, the above Promise will automatically resolve, but what if it needs to be rejected? Maybe I am still thinking with jQuery's `.done(), .fail() and .always()`.

> But for the life of me, despite all the Googling I do, I cannot find how to fully incorporate all the functions of a plain JS `Promise` with a jQuery AJAX request.

Thus, I am asking the stackoverflow community for insight into this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there something that the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) is lacking?

Comment: @RayNicholus TBH, I never even hear of Fetch API until you just mentioned it... Now I am getting through [Jake Archibald's](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/) blog on it. Maybe I will use it, but let's see also if there is an answer to my question above. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `Promise` isn't really your savior here. The issue you have is that you need to call the `console.log('res =', res);` after the AJAX request is done using the `.done()` and `.fail()` methods.

```
function ajaxCall(type, url, data, dataType) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: dataType,
  });
}

//this is inside $(document).ready - I just skipped some lines
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function(e) {
  var res = ajaxCall('POST', '/Login', { 'username': $('#username').val(), 'password': $('#password').val() }, 'json');
  res.done(function (data) {
    console.log('res =', data);
  });
});
```

If you really want to use a real `Promise`, you can do something like

```
function ajaxCall(type, url, data, dataType) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
      type: type,
      url: url,
      data: data,
      dataType: dataType,
    }).done(function (data) {
      resolve(data);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      reject(errorThrown);
    });
  });
}

//this is inside $(document).ready - I just skipped some lines
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function(e) {
  var res = ajaxCall('POST', '/Login', { 'username': $('#username').val(), 'password': $('#password').val() }, 'json');
  res.then(function (data) {
    console.log('res = ', data);
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
});
```